# spring jpa specification join cause n+1

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa Specification API and want to query and fetch the parent entity with its associations, without causing N+1 problems.

Code of all entities was below. There are two onetoone associations.
To achieve join query without N+1, I have tried two ways: `root.fetch("policy",JoinType.LEFT)` and `@EntityGraph annotation`.

Althrough both methods will log the first main SQL with join clause correctly.
But
with root.fetch method, I got the exception described below.

> .hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias3,role=com.xxx.model.OrderTrack.policy,tableName=pro_lafs_policy,tableAlias=policy3_,origin=tordertrack ordertrack0_,columns={ordertrack0_.billno ,className=com.xxx.model.Policy}}

with EntityGraph, the N+1 still happen, I can saw this in the log.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tordertrack")
@JsonAutoDetect
public class OrderTrack {
    private Long oid;
    private String billno;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "billno",referencedColumnName = "bill_no",updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Policy policy;
}

@Entity
public class Policy{
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "BILL_NO")
    private String billNo;
}


//in Service method:
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OrderTrack> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    root.fetch("policy",JoinType.LEFT);
    root.fetch("returnVisit",JoinType.LEFT);
}
service.findAll(specification,pageable);

//with @EntityGraph 
@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"policy","returnVisit"})
Page<OrderTrack> findAll(Specification<OrderTrack> var1, Pageable var2);
```

I will appreciate for your help.

Comment: the exception in the question was thrown when use pagination; so the question become why I still get N+1 queries after I have use entity graph, only the first main query was added left outer join clause, but It still generate sub queries.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?